# Draw wave curve on top of image slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to implement below like effect on top of image slider, please guide me [image]

Answer (score 4):

You can create custom `ClipPath`

```
class Clipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
   @override
   Path getClip(Size size) {
       Path path = Path();
       path.lineTo(0, size.height);
       path.quadraticBezierTo(
       size.width / 4, size.height - 40, size.width / 2, size.height - 20);
       path.quadraticBezierTo(
       3 / 4 * size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height - 30);
      path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

      return path;
   }

 @override
 bool shouldReclip(Clipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

find sample [snippet](https://gist.github.com/kishorejethava/5309df0b66d97e3d0b8f8c4326b71c5c)

Note : this is basic idea you to have modify by your own requirement

sample output
[image]

Comment: This is something different behavior, actually wave move horizontally with sliding image, but clippath not doing this. can you guide me further about this.